# 2D MMORPG creating using C# WPF

Tags: wpf, 2d

I know it's not very efficient, but I am creating a 2D MMORPG in C# WPF.
So far I've created a server and a login (with Database & sql and stuff).
Everything is great and I have a pretty good idea on how to make a chat, inventory system and all. 
Right now, I'm stuck with maps and the scrolling system. 
As you should know, 2D games usually are side-scrolling, means if you go left the screen goes with you. And that is a thing that I don't know how to do.
My "Map" is actually a picture of a tile and background around it, I don't have any idea on how to make a complex map with path, spawn points etc.

I'd be glad if someone could give me ideas or any thing the could help me in the process.

Another thing is the character animation - so far I'm using a picture as character, and it looks pretty lame. I mean, the character is beautiful, we are drawing the characters ourself, but I just don't know how to fuse them into the game with animations and such without being lame and just switching pictures. There must be an efficient way. I hope you could help me :\
(I'm using blend for animations like fade, but I don't think that Storyboards are serious enough for a character animation.)

P.S
I do know that WPF isn't suitable for 2d games, idk why tough, but I know it doesn't. And still I want to develop my game with it.

Thanks to the helpers <3

EDIT:
I moved to Unity, it's easy and simple, and uses C# so I like it. I already moved my client to there without any effort, LOVE IT :P

Thanks again to the helpers. wish me luck ;)

Comment: as much as I love WPF, I'm afraid you'll constantly hit platform incapabilities when doing something like that. It's just not intended for such a thing, and therefore the necessary framework-level features are not there. For example, in order to animate your character you will have to do pure XAML geometries and animate them, which is extremely burdensome compared to other frameworks which are intended for game development and therefore provide such capabilities.

Comment: Okay, so are there any 2D MMORPG software that is good for developing and using C# or another easy language?